# Customizing the home page layout in lightning

Tags: lightning

I created a custom object called "XYZ". On this object I created a custom picklist "123" with the following values: "Open" "Working" "Closed".

The requirement I have is that I need to display all the records whose statuses are "Working" & "Closed" on the home page in the lightning interface.

Is it possible to get the list of records from a custom object with the picklist values as "Working" & " Closed" on the Home page by using configuration? We are using the professional edition .

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom report with report chart using "XYZ" records filtered by "Working" & "Closed".

And then, put the `Report Chart` on home page.

You can go through [Building a Custom Home Page for Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/lightning_app_builder/lightning_app_builder_homepage) trailhead

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a normal list view on your object tab and display the list view on the home page. I think the element is call Filter List in the Lightning App Builder.